# Add attribute filter 'manufacturer' to 'reports/product_collection'

Tags: reports, collection-filtering, join-table

I want to filter `reports/product_collection` by attribute `manufacturer`.

I try with this:

```
    $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->joinAttribute('manufacturer','catalog_product/manufacturer','entity_id',null,'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attr, array('eq' => $attr_id))
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
    ->setPageSize($productCount);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
    ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
```

But the lines:

```
    ->joinAttribute('manufacturer','catalog_product/manufacturer','entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter($attr, array('eq' => $attr_id))
```

Do not have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Here's the **SOLUTION**, including a filter to grouped products. Thanks to Amit! For pointing me there!

```
$_reportIds = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
    ->getColumnValues('entity_id');

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array($_reportIds)))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => $attr_id));

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other way,you can do.

1. **First get product ids from that report product**
2. Then create a product collection by
   `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()`  and then filter
   `that collection  using first set product ids`
   3.**Now  that collection by  manufacturer attribute**

### Code may be:

```
    $_ids = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
         ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
        ->getColumnValues('entity_id');
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection ->addIdFilter( $_ids);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
        ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection );
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
        ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 'ValueID'));

`
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked besides a tipo. Please change entity to entity_id.

Comment: :) done Changes;...

Comment: I want to know ... how to filter ('reports/product_collection') according to order status....plz help.@AmitBera